# google translate sudently stopped working i didint change the code any way

Tags: python, google-translate

Google translate libary stopped working.
I didn't change anything about my code and it worked like an hour ago. I don't understand what is happening.
Here is my code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import time
K = Translator()

def anna_sanat(x):
  K = Translator()
  a = K.translate(x,dest="sv",src="en").text
  b = K.translate(x,dest="fi",src="en").text
  return [x,a,b]

f = open("sanat.txt",mode="r",encoding="utf-8")

g = f.read()
f.close()
g = g.split(" ")
h = []
for i in g:
  h += i.split("\n")
for i in h:
  print(i)
  print(anna_sanat(i.replace("\"","")))
  time.sleep(1)
```

and here is the error message:

```
Magnus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\Desktop\Koodaus\uusin Python\ruotsi\ruotsipeli.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(anna_sanat(i.replace("\"","")))
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\Desktop\Koodaus\uusin Python\ruotsi\ruotsipeli.py", line 7, in anna_sanat
    a = K.translate(x,dest="sv",src="en").text
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 172, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src)
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 81, in _translate
    data = utils.format_json(r.text)
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\utils.py", line 62, in format_json
    converted = legacy_format_json(original)
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googletrans\utils.py", line 54, in legacy_format_json
    converted = json.loads(text)
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Taavi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: It looks like `K.translate` is expecting JSON but you're giving it plain text

Answer (score 0):

Oh I know this one, I think this happens because googletrans makes requests to google translate directly, and after a while, google translate starts returning nothing, the only way that I know to get around this is to add a `time.sleep(*Large number here*)` and test again after that.